# S3 Static Website through Route 53. Redirect to page if path doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have been following an AWS tutorial for making a static website in S3 through Route 53. I have made the basic website, set up the S3 bucket, and set the DNS zone to Alias to the Bucket. My issue is that I am unable to redirect to the page if a subdomain doesn't exist.

For some reason, I cannot find a guide to address this. If I enter the correct website www.mynewsite.com (example), it goes to the page properly. What I am trying to do is allow a URL like www.mynewsite.com/test to redirect back to www.mynewsite.com, instead of 404 not found. Is there a way to do this? Even the AWS tutorial page would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is an [advanced conditional redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects) with S3 routing rules.

```xml
<RoutingRules>
 <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals></KeyPrefixEquals>
        <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <Protocol>https</Protocol>
        <HostName>example.com</HostName>
        <ReplaceKeyWith></ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
 </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

This will cause the web site endpoint to 
redirect any request that would have returned a 403 back to `https://example.com/`... and 403 is what S3 returns by default for nonexistent objects (because, by default, S3 does not reveal the nonexistence of objects with a 404 -- everything is simply `403 Forbidden`).

If you have made your bucket excessively public then you'll need to use `<HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>` instead of 403 but if this is the case, you have allowed unauthenticated callers to list your bucket, and you should probably remove that permission.

If you are using client-side rendering and you want to track the nonexistent page by making it extractable in the URI, you can use something like `<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>?x-not-found=/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>` instead of `<ReplaceKeyWith></ReplaceKeyWith>`.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I swear I followed that tutorial and did not see this. Maybe there are too many AWS tutorials. Anyways, this is good. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do for this case is have the index document set to index.html, and then set the error document also to index.html - any 404's will simply redirect back to your home page.

Give it a try, wait about 3 minutes and it should work.